# Help deleting fields from an HTML table

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

So I am not sure exactly how to tag this one, but basically I have a dynamically loaded HTML table, that contains values that will can be deleted, currently I am using check boxes for the user to decide which row to delete.  Here is my code so far:

```
      <table id="comments" align="center" width="59%">
    <thead>
      <th class="headerClass" width="7%">Delete</th>
      <th width="15%" class="headerClass">Date</th>
      <th class="headerClass" width="15%">Employee</th>
      <th class="headerClass">Comment</th>
    </thead>
      <tbody>           
<%
  while (result.next()) { 

        commentDate = StringUtils.defaultString(result.getString("commentDate"));
        commentUser = StringUtils.defaultString(result.getString("cName"));
        comment = StringUtils.defaultString(result.getString("xbs_comment"));

%>

      <tr>
        <td class="normal"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="normal"><%=commentDate%></td>
        <td class="normal"><%=commentUser%></td>
        <td class="normal" width="68%"><%=comment%></td>                
      </tr> 
  </tbody>     
</table>    
  <label for="comment"><h4>Add a Comment:</h4></label> 
  <textarea cols="105" id="comment" name="comment" rows="4"></textarea> 
<br />

<div align="center" class="submit">
  <input class="submit" width="10%" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Basically I have a table with comments, the user can add a comment using the submit button, but I would like them to also be able to use the check box to delete comments.  Do i need another form tag w/ a delete button, or can I use just this one submit button?  Also if I do stay with the check boxes, how do I let the back end of my program(function and servlet) know which was checked?  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I added jsp and java tags, so someone here with expertise with these language will see this and can help you. I know these tags needed to solve your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this along with the same submit. And also you can delete comment via ajax then you may reload the page upon success in deletion.

Here is some of the way to delete the comment by using the same submit button. And I assume that the user has the access to delete all the comments in the table.

```
but I would like them to also be able to use the check box to delete comments
```

To do this you must assign a value on the checkbox that are unique for every comments. Usually the primary key or ID in the row that represent each comment.

Use a single name for every checkbox to do a multiple delete. Sample below

**comments.jsp**

```
<form name="commentForm" action="addDelete.jsp">
    <div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th><th>Date</th><th>User</th><th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% 
          for(Comment cmnt : commentList){
        %>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="<%=cmnt.getCmntId()%>" name="cmntId" /></td>
                <td><%=cmnt.getCmntDate()%></td>
                <td><%=cmnt.getCmntUser()%></td>
                <td><%=cmnt.getCmntComment()%></td>
            </tr>
        <%              
          }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="newComment">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="Id_of_the_user">
</div>
</form>
```

This is just an example, so focus more on the part where have a checkbox.

**addDelete.jsp**

Now on the adddelete.jsp, you could have two queries with different function. first is for adding new comments and second is the deletion of the comment(s).

To get the list of comment to be delete store it in an array. And also get the other fields.

```
String[] cmntIds = request.getParameterValue("cmntId"); //This store all the cmntId that are checked in the previous checkbox.
String newComment = request.getParameterValue("newComment");
String userId = request.getParameterValue("userId"); //This can be in a session

//Some function you may need
deleteComment(cmntIds); //Execute a query to delete comment using the cmntIds
inserNewComment(newComment, userId); //Execute a query to add the new comment using newComment and userId if there is a comment attached.
```

Beyond this part I hope you can handle what function you will need to do what you want.

Comment: This is tremendous, thank you.  I have two questions though, I am unsure how to execute that particular "for" loop.  Will I just need for(Comment cmnt : commentList){.....or do I need to include the other things that were in my previous while loop?  Also, are you saying that addDelete.jsp will be my servlet and use two functions to add/delete?

Comment: Is there anyway to use something different than that particular "for" statement?  I dont think I am running the correct java to be able to use that syntax....

Comment: You can also do this with a `while loop`. I just make an object that have a data, to use in my example. And I'm more used with `for` so I used this one. And if you are able to run the `while` I guess there will be no need to add other things on your code, except you want to other utilities from Java. Then you will need to add/import its package. The addDelete.jsp is not actually a servlet though you can use a servlet that forward the response and request here. But you can also use it in your servlet as in a MVC pattern. You can use two function if you are going to use my sample code.